# MS Access specifying the index when selecting

Tags: database

I want to use  specified index with query. Just like INDEXED BY in SQLite.

I can't find it in MS Access.

Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access will try to optimize the query itself by analyzing the available indexes, and making a choice that it thinks is best. Unlike SQL Server, there is no HINT operator. The best you can do is set to ordinal positions of your WHERE clause, placing the most covered indexes first, and that should help Access optimize.

SELECT * FROM tblCustomers WHERE City= 'Denver' AND CustomerName Like 'A*'

The city reduces the set the most first, then the CustomerName filter will be easier.

Hope this helps...